# How to avoid macro usage when defining an easy to maintain function entry exit logger

Tags: c++

i wish to write a function entry/exit logger with two primary goals:

1. Do not to refer to the implicit variables like `__func__` in
   each and every function. (Because it would be a lot to change for ex
   if i want to use `__PRETTY_FUNCTION__` when i have gcc)
2. Avoid macros.

But i somehow am unable to meet goal number 2.

The best i could do is as below:

```cxx
#define LOG_ENTRY_EXIT() entry_exit_logger e(__func__);
using func_name_type = const char*;

class entry_exit_logger{
public:
    entry_exit_logger(const func_name_type fname) : func_name(fname){
        std::cout << "-------Enter: " << func_name << "------" << std::endl;
    }

    ~entry_exit_logger(){
        std::cout << "-------Exit: " << func_name << "------" << std::endl;
    }
private:
    const func_name_type func_name;
};

void test_entry_exit(){
    LOG_ENTRY_EXIT();
}

int main(){
    test_entry_exit();
    return 0;
}
```

How can i do this without using a macro?
Or is this an example for an appropriate usage of macro?

Comment: FYI, the macro you present doesn't work correctly. It logs the exit prematurely.

Comment: @StoryTeller yes, i will correct it and edit the post, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: "Avoid macros." - that's a bit dogmatic. It's not like macros are universally bad - they have their applications, and this is one of those situations (that said, I wouldn't personally do logging this way because IO is always blocking. As you're using `cout` I guess this is for debugging only? If so, then use `::OutputDebugString` on Windows or `syslog(3)` on Linux, if consider using `std::clog` instead of `std::cout`.

Comment: if your compiler doesn't support [std::source_location](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location) then you've got to use macros really

Comment: @StoryTeller changed: ``` #define LOG_ENTRY_EXIT() entry_exit_logger(__func__);``` to ```#define LOG_ENTRY_EXIT() entry_exit_logger e(__func__);```. Now the macro seems to report the exit properly.

Comment: @Dai Thanks. Used cout for illustrative purpose

Comment: @AlanBirtles will checkout your solution. Thanks!